# Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found in live server

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

What happen to my code, after uploading to godaddy server it has an error but in localhost their is no error.

[image]

```
public function activate($activation_key='') {

        $userData = $this->Users->find('all')->where(['activation_key' => $activation_key,'status' => 0 ])->first();

            if( !empty($userData) ){
               $activeStatus = 1;
               $status = $this->Users->updateAll(array('Users.status' => 
       $activeStatus), array('Users.id' => $userData->id));

      //// additional code
    }
    }
```

stack trace error is on this line

```
 $status = $this->Users->updateAll(array('Users.status' =>
   $activeStatus), array('Users.id' => $userData->id));
```

Needing your help

Comment: Can You confirm column `status` exists on production server?

Comment: yes it has a field status (int)

Comment: Can You remove files from `tmp/cache/models`?

Comment: the error still occur after removing the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You syntax is incorrect:

```
UPDATE `users` SET `Users`.`status`...
```

Should be:

```
UPDATE `users` AS  `Users` SET `Users`.`status`...
```

Remove `Users` aliases from `updateAll`.

Comment: I don't know:) Check examples on https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#bulk-updates

Comment: It's because the syntax for using aliases in `UPDATE` queries differs between the supported DMBS', and `updateAll()` (and `deleteAll()` for that matter) currently also do not support joins, hence alias support isn't required anyways. The aliases are automatically removed from conditions in order to avoid conflicts with association conditions. @JervynPaller

Comment: so thats why? it runs in my localhost not in live environment? because of not supported DMBS